# ABP Commercial Db2 Connection

Tags: abp

How can I connect to IBM DB2 database with Abp Commercial project infrastructure?
I know there is ABP commercial sql and mongodb support. Is there DB2 support?

Comment: what does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

ABP Commercial is based on the ABP Framework. According to [this document](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Other-DBMS) there is no DB2 support. I can recommend the postgres database if you start new project